# How do I add a highlight to text for "find" function?

Tags: vb.net, highlight

I am trying to have one text box with a lot of text and another with a string to be found in the first text box. I used this to find if the string was located:

```
    Text1 = TextBox1.Text
    WordtoFind = TextBox2.Text
    O = Text1.IndexOf(WordtoFind)

    If (O = -1) Then
        Label.Text = "String was not found"
    Else
        Label.Text = "String was found"
    End If
```

Can someone help me with the highlighting of the found word? Thanks.

Comment: WebForms? WinForms? Other?

Comment: you can do this using RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If (O = -1) Then
    Label.Text = "String was not found"
Else
    Label.Text = "String was found"
    TextBox1.Focus()
    TextBox1.Select(O, WordtoFind.Length)
End If
```

Edit

```
Dim wordPosition As Integer

Text1 = TextBox1.Text
WordtoFind = TextBox2.Text
wordPosition = Text1.IndexOf(WordtoFind)

If (wordPosition = -1) Then
    Label.Text = "String was not found"
Else
    Label.Text = "String was found"
    TextBox1.Focus()
    TextBox1.Select(wordPosition, WordtoFind.Length)
End If
```

valter

Comment: This does highlight and is what I am looking for, but the

  Textbox1.Select(0, WordtoFind.Length)

Just starts the highlighting at the beginning of the textbox due to the "0" in there. With the select function that first value must be an integer, so I have been messing around trying to find how to start the select at the first occurrence of the WordtoFind, but have not found a way yet.

Comment: @Jim It is not *0 (zero)* but the letter *O* as in your code.